# How can I create a confirmation link in email?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet which serves as form.
What I basically want to do is generate a link that when you click it it will trigger an Apps Script function.
So the question is more "How to generate a link that when is clicked (requested) it will run an Apps script function?"

Later I need to send this link to a specific email but that one I do know how to do.

Comment: What will do the Google Apps Script function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve an HTML page with the doGet/doPost method, and when opened it triggers any Apps Script function plus shows a success message, you can also use an AJAX/XMLHttpRequest from any other page to trigger apps script functions with conjunction with the doGet/doPost.

How to serve a HTML page from Apps Script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

How to execute GAS functions from a page deployed from Apps Script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication